# Why cant i call 'explicit C(const C&)'?

Tags: c++

[Heres the link to code and the error](http://codepad.org/OVZJZexp)

I dont understand why the line `return (const C&)cc;` doesnt work.

Heres a paste of code and error

```
#include <stdio.h>

class C 
{
public:
    int i;
    explicit C(const C&)   // an explicit copy constructor
    {
        printf("\nin the copy constructor");
    }
    explicit C(int i )   // an explicit constructor
    {
        printf("\nin the constructor");
    }

    C()
    {
        i = 0;
    }
};

class C2
{
public:
    int i;
    explicit C2(int i )   // an explicit constructor
    {
    } 
};

C f(C c)
{   // C2558
//    c.i = 2;
//    return c;   // first call to copy constructor
C cc;
return (const C&)cc;
}

void f2(C2)
{
}

void g(int i)
{
//    f2(i);   // C2558
    // try the following line instead
     f2(C2(i));
}

int main()
{
    C c, d;
    d = f(c);   // c is copied
}
```

Output:

> In function 'C f(C)': Line 36: error:
>   no matching function for call to
>   'C::C(const C&)' compilation
>   terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Comment: Looks like the example is taken from this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1y7x448(VS.80).aspx . There it mentions to remove the explicit keyword for the program to compile.

Comment: Can you also explain what you want to solve by making the copy constructor explicit? I am not familiar with that idiom.

Comment: Its just an experiment. I was trying to figure out how to call an explicit copy constructor. it doesnt seem possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples of calling the explicit copy-constructor:

- http://ideone.com/bV4S7
- http://ideone.com/G0OYi

Of course, pass-by-value and return-by-value always call the copy constructor implicitly, so declaring the copy constructor explicit will prevent this (not necessarily a bad thing).

Comment: Oh i understand! its not actually the line but the fact it is being return by value which is NOT consider explicit. I completely understand now.

Answer (score 2):

Line 36 requires a implicit call of the copy constructor, which you have declared explicit for some reason.
Remove the explicit on the copy and you will be fine.
It makes sense to have it on `C::C(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return C(cc);
```

This is an explicit call to the copy constructor. Casting to a reference is not.

Comment: I don't think that should work. It creates an explicit copy that in turn needs an implicit copy into the return value.

Comment: You can edit the line and hit submit which will show you the error code. It didnt work. Maybe its impossible to call the copy constructor explicitly? http://codepad.org/TgE8sV4G

Comment: Maybe it is impossible. http://codepad.org/OOFQJ7pY i tried `const C& cc =ccc;return C::C(cc);` with no success.